# JavaScript: Find nested [quote]

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, nested, bbcode

I want to do form validation at user side with JavaScript (jQuery is also used). The goal is to remove nested bbCode `[quote]` tags deeper than level 2. Say, we have this text:

```
[quote=SoundMAX][quote=Laplundik][quote=SoundMAX]
blahblahblah[/quote]
blahblah
[/quote]
blah[/quote]
```

And get this:

```
[quote=SoundMAX][quote=Laplundik]
blahblah
[/quote]
blah[/quote]
```

My only idea is to .replace `[quote]` with `<div>`, then create DOM object and remove anything deeper than 2 with jQuery, and parse all backwards to bbCode. But that solution seems too complicated, are there more elegant one?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for nice solutions. Based on darioo's answer, I did this:

```
var text=$('#edit-privatemsgbody').val();
var tmp=[];
var level=0;

for (var i=0,l=text.length;i<l;i++){
 if(text[i]=='['&&text[i+1]=='q') level++; 
 if(text[i-6]=='q'&&text[i-7]=='/'&&text[i-8]=='[') level--;
 if(level<3) tmp.push(text[i]);
}
alert(tmp.join(''));
```

Which works just fine.

But idealmachine's solution was like a flash. I didn't know about replace callback function parameters before, now that is handy! I'll settle with it.

Comment: *Not* with regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @idealmachine: That's the reason I have asked for another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can use regex if you look at it as a limited tool that cannot handle the nesting itself. The [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) string method can call a function to find the replacement text for each match, which allows us to track how deep we are in the markup structure (code also posted at http://jsfiddle.net/Zbgr3/3/):

```
var quoteLevel = 0;

alert(s.replace(/\[(\/?)quote[^\]]*\]|./gi, function(tag, slash) {
    // Opening tag?
    if(tag.length > 1 && !slash.length) quoteLevel += 1;
    // What to strip
    var strip = quoteLevel > 2;
    // Closing tag?
    if(tag.length > 1 && slash.length) quoteLevel -= 1;

    if(strip) return '';
    return tag;
}));
```

If you want some tolerance for errors in the markup, you could add some extra code that, for example, prevents quoteLevel from falling below zero.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular array as a stack. Every time you encounter `[quote]`, increase your array by one using its `push()` method. When you encounter `[/quote]`, decrease your array by one using its `pop()` method.

If you encounter `[quote]` and your array length is 2, remove that `[quote]`, and remove the next `[/quote]` you encounter.

If you don't have the same number of open and closed quotes, then you'll have to handle that in a way you find appropriate.